# PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target - imported CERT

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, get-request

I am trying to use get request on site with REST API. However the link to acces it is an IP address and I am getting the:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

When I use the same exact link in browser, it works.

How can I solve this issue?

Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
    System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyHost", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" );
    System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyPort", "xxxx" );


    URL requestLink = ismTicketManager.UrlEncode.convertToURLEscapingIllegalCharacters("https://xx.xx.xx.xx/e/528f5016-6fd9-403f-85e4-5a54bb2498b9/api/v1/problem/feed?relativeTime=30mins&Api-Token=xxxxx");

    try {
        HttpURLConnection targetConn = (HttpURLConnection)requestLink.openConnection();
        targetConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        System.out.println(targetConn.getResponseCode());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Connection failed");
    }

    static {
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> hostname.equals("127.0.0.1"));
}

}
```

I exported the cert from firefox and imported it into the  cacerts file:
The cacerts file list looks like this:

restapi, 25-Sep-2018, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): AB:6D:C6:2E:9F:B3:D9:48:1E:A9:84:AA:DD:03:64:1D:7C:08:42:CE

How can I solve this?

EDIT: Solved thanks to Guillaume.
My problem was that I have program files/JDK and program files/JRE. I was importing into the cacerts file in JDK, while eclipse was using the JRE. This was discovered thansk to the -Djavax.net.debug=ssl VM argument.

Also the IP in :

```
static {
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> hostname.equals("10.31.17.38"));
}
```

should be equal to the one in the variable requestLink that I am using. In fact when I did not do this, I got an error telling me exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the website does not send the full certification path (including the root).
Try adding this VM option: `-Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true`

When launching the Java program from command line, your command should look like that (as explained in the [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html))

```
java -Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true <Main Class>
```

When launching from Eclipse the option should be added under "VM Arguments:"

Comment: Stupid question, but how do I add the VM option?

Comment: I am using eclipse. I added it among the Run Configuration > Arguments. Now when I run it it just hangs up somewhere.

Comment: See my edit, it should be under "VM Arguments", not "Arguments". "Arguments" is what your program will receive in its 'public static void main(String[] args)' method

Comment: It's hard for me to say what's happening, try using the debugger (F11) and pause the main thread to see what it's doing

Comment: I cannot pause it, the button is greyed out, so I used a few printlines, it appears to hang up on System.out.println(targetConn.getResponseCode());

Comment: Alright, I let it run for a while and it finished with the same error.

Comment: Is it possible I added the cert wrong? Or with wrong alias or something? Or the cert itself is wrong?

Comment: If you also add this option -Djavax.net.debug=ssl you will get a lot of debug logs from the SSL layers, that might give you some insights. It could be that the root is not trusted, or revoked or using a deprecated algo, again it's hard for me to see what's going on

Comment: Okay, I have the debug. Anything specific I need to look for?

Comment: You should be able to see if your certificate is loaded: at the begining it's loaded all the trusted certs and CAs

Comment: Alright. I have JDK and JRE folders. It is apparently using the JRE folder, but I have it imported in the JDK folder. I will import it to the JRE instead.

Comment: Ah I was wondering if there were multiple JRE on your computer, I should have asked. You can set Eclipse use the JRE of your JDK : Window / Preferences / Java / Installed JREs

Comment: Alright so it works now. The mistakes I made were that I was importing the cert into the cacerts in program files/JDK folder while eclipse is using the program files/JRE. So what I did is I imported the cert into the program files/JRE cacerts file, then I had to change the IP in the static method where hostname.equals("same ip as the one I am using in requestLink") and the response code was 200. Woo. Thank you so much

Comment: Which one should I let the eclipse use? The JDK or JRE?

Comment: It probably won't matter, provided that you import your certs in the same JRE ;)  Glad to hear that it's working!